# How can i change display name with code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dynamic

I want to dynamically change display name  from within the application. Is there a way it? i dont want to use .plist. i want to use with xcode from application. Thanks

${PRODUCT_NAME} How can i call this value with code ?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific ... show us some code.

Comment: I dont think you can do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The app name is defined in the **app's info.plist** file..

That come in `Main Bundle`..and `iOS does not allow anything to be written and updated in Main Bundle..`

So you cant programmatically change contents of app info.plist having app's name...bundle identifier ..etc

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. The Info.plist and everything in the app bundle is read-only once it's installed on an iPhone.

Add the following code to get the product name

```
NSDictionary *infoPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *appName = [infoPList objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

appName is the value of "Bundle display name" or Product Name

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so.

You can *localise* it -- i.e., display different names depending on the language in use -- but I don't think you can change the name dynamically. That's probably a good thing... it could get pretty confusing if abused.